# 4 parameter logistic fit

Tags: logistic, modeling, logit, biostatistics

I am trying to fit some enzyme inhibition data by using 4PL.
My problem is that the assay I used (AlphaLISA) to generate the data can not be used at high inhibitor concentrations thus, the inhibition can not reach its maximum and IC50 can not be calculated.

My question is whether the 4PL analysis is still valid in such case or should I use a different analysis tool?

In addition should I average duplicates or should i use them individually as separate data points when applying 4PL?

Comment: Why wouldn't the 2PL model be appropriate here?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a 4PL analysis since your software will calculate the IC50 or inflection point for you even if it is off curve.
The software will iterate solutions for the four parameters in the 4PL function and seach for the best values of the parameters giving you the closest fit to your calibrators. You can determine if the curve matches your values properly if the curve fits your data points or by looking at the sum of squares value, this should be small.
You can choose if you average the values of the duplicates or use them separately. My favourite is to average them as this will slightly reduce the effect of outliers on the curve-fitting.